# Is there a log redact feature in .net core?

Tags: c#, .net-core, serialization, redaction

I need a redacting feature like nodeJS pino in .net core.

I need to log objects but since they hold sensitive data, i cant log property values. But i need to log as much information as possible. For example i have

```
public class Car 
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Size { get; set; }
    public int Height { get; set; }
    public List<Tire> Tires { get; set; } = new List<Tire>();
}
public class Tire 
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Diameter { get; set; }
    public int Area { get; set; }
}
```

And let

```
Car car = new Car();
car.Height = 1;
car.Name = "good boy";
car.Size = "long";

Tire tire1 = new Tire();
tire1.Area = 10;
tire1.Diameter = 20;
tire1.Name = "tire 1";

Tire tire2 = new Tire();
tire2.Area = 22;
tire2.Diameter = 33;

car.Tires.Add(tire1);
car.Tires.Add(tire2);
```

I want

```
logObject(car)
```

produce a string

```
{
  "Name": "string",
  "Size": "string",
  "Height": "int",
  "Tires": [
    {
      "Name": "string",
      "Diameter": "int",
      "Area": "int"
    },
    {
      "Name": "null",
      "Diameter": int,
      "Area": int
    }
  ]
}
```

Note that when the value is null, it prints null.

Is there this kind of logger in .net core? Or is there a serializer like this?

Comment: How would a logger know which of your tires it is allowed to log?

Comment: why? all of them are allowed. @nvoigt

Comment: But the whole point of the question as demonstrated in your example output is to redact one specific tire, right?

Comment: no, redact values like name of the tire. Why do i want to redact tires?  @nvoigt

Comment: So how is the logger supposed to know to redact the name of the second tire, but not of the first?

Comment: just redact all values. why do one redact one but the other? @nvoigt

Comment: Because it is in the example you posted?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242909/discussion-between-yilmaz-and-nvoigt).